# Cannot add a UIDatePicker to an xib without generating an Internal Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uidatepicker

I am using xCode 4.0.2 and trying to create a view controller with an xib that contains a UIDatePicker. Whenever I try to drag a UIDatePicker object to the view in the xib I get an Internal Error alert. This is a universal app and I am using an xib targeted for the iPhone.

Has anyone else experienced this or have any suggestions on how to work around this problem?

For now I am going to work around it by adding the UIDatePicker to the view in code.

Also, when I click the Crash button in the alert I am not getting the Crash Reporter. Isn't the Crash Reporter supposed to come up automatically? If this is a bug, how can I otherwise report it?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score -1):

if you are using the Xcode UI and it crashes, assuming you don't have any huge environmental problems, no disk space... etc, that is a bug; and you should report it to:
[bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)